# What does "hardy" mean in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: apt

I see entries in /etc/apt/sources.list that say:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
```

I am using Ubuntu 8.04, and I don't know what "hardy" means, though I suspect it has something to do with version?

Answer (score 13):

Hardy is the name of the 8.04 Release, "Hardy Heron".

Each Ubuntu Release follows the same pattern, `year.month` numbers for versioning, e.g `8.04` `8.10`, `10.04` (usually 2 releases every year) and a code name.

Ubuntu Releases are:

- 4.10 - Warty Warthog
- 5.04 - Hoary Hedgehog
- 5.10 - Breezy Badger
- 6.06 - Dapper Drake
- 6.10 - Edgy Eft
- 7.04 - Feisty Fawn
- 7.10 - Gutsy Gibbon
- 8.04 - Hardy Heron
- 8.10 - Intrepid Ibex
- 9.04 - Jaunty Jackalope
- 9.10 - Karmic Koala
- 10.04 - Lucid Lynx

They appear on your sources list to indicate which release(version) of the repository you are using.

PS: You must have also realized by now, that Ubuntu releases follow an alphabetical naming order, always using an adjective and an animal name. The next Ubuntu release (10.10) will be named Maverick Meerkat.

PS2: The oficial Ubuntu page with all codenames, plus some discarded alternatives names can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames), if you are curious about it.

Comment: I wonder what will happen when they ran out of letters ;-)

Comment: Probably start over. They already reused the H. :)

Comment: It's useful wen searching for an issue online to include the version adjective.  This narrows your search results to the version in question. e.g. google: hardy sound driver

Comment: Decio, it would probably be worth linking to the [release codenames wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames).

Comment: good idea. done. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Letter name is the "codename" during testing--when released it becomes the number release.